# how to do a alert message

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, jquery, dynamic-visualforce

How to alert message the **events section and resources section** so that I can check whether all my events are being loaded into the VF page or not.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'agendaDay,agendaTwoDay,agendaWeek,month'
                },
                 views: {
                    agendaTwoDay: {
                        type: 'agenda',
                        duration: { days: 5 },

                        // views that are more than a day will NOT do this behavior by default
                        // so, we need to explicitly enable it
                        groupByResource: true

                        //// uncomment this line to group by day FIRST with resources underneath
                        //groupByDateAndResource: true
                    }
                },

                editable: true,
                defaultDate:new Date(),
                editable: true,
                //schedulerLicenseKey: 'GPL-My-Project-Is-Open-Source',

                    resources: [
                     <apex:repeat value="{!venue_resource}" var="v">
                     {
                             id: "{!v.Venueid}",
                             title: "{!v.titlename}",
                             eventColor: 'orange'
                     },
                     </apex:repeat>

                ],

                events:
                    [
                        //At run time, this APEX Repeat will reneder the array elements for the events array
                      <apex:repeat value="{!events}" var="e">
                            {
                                id:'{!e.eventid}',
                                resourceId: '{!e.venueids }',
                                start: '{!e.startString}',
                                end: '{!e.endString}',
                                title: '{!e.title}',
                                url: '{!e.url}',
                                allDay: '{!e.allDay}',
                                className: '{!e.className}'

                            },
                        </apex:repeat>
                    ],

                    select: function(start, end, jsEvent, view, resource) {
                    console.log(  
                        'select',
                        start.format(),
                        end.format(),
                        resource ? resource.id : '(no resource)'
                    );
                },
                dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view, resource) {
                    console.log(
                        'dayClick',
                        date.format(),
                        resource ? resource.id : '(no resource)'
                    );
                }

            });
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two events that represent the two importants milestones while your page loads.

The `DOMContentLoaded` event fires at the end of `Stage #2` when your page's DOM is fully parsed.

The load event fires at the end of `Stage #3` once your page has fully loaded.

You can use these events to time when exactly you want your code to run.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", theDomHasLoaded, false);
window.addEventListener("load", pageFullyLoaded, false);

function theDomHasLoaded(e) {
    alert('The Dom Has Loaded');
}

function pageFullyLoaded(e) {
    alert('Page Fully Loaded');
}
```

For more info check this out http://www.kirupa.com/html5/running_your_code_at_the_right_time.htm

Comment: Can I Individually do a  id: "{!v.Venueid}",    title: "{!v.titlename}"popup ,rather to load on complete page load.

Comment: @kishore what the issue you are trying to solve?

Comment: Will explain u briefly, 
`resources: [

                 {
                         id: "a002800000KsTOOAA3",
                         title: "Lunch",
                          eventColor: 'orange'
                 } } `
**and**

Comment: events:
`         [
 {
  id:'00U28000006tPi4EAE',
resourceId: 'a002800000KsTOOAA3',
start: 'Wed, 23 Dec 2015 17:30:00 IST',
end: 'Wed, 23 Dec 2015 22:30:00 IST',
title: 'HP Lunch',
url: '/00U28000006tPi4EAE',
allDay: 'false',
className: 'event-personal'
                                  
 } ] `

Comment: **I get all the values in backend (View Frame Source) of the page but its not loading into the page.

So i wanted to know whether these values are hitting in the Page repeat panel. I have problem only with Events not getting loaded into the page where as the Resources is working Fine**

Comment: @kishore few things. If `Resources` working then `Events` should work. if not then what you can do place your JS below your page mean end of your page so what happened all the elements will generates first after that your script will execute. that will solve your problem.

Comment: I need to connect with u. Lemme know how do i contact u, if u can help me out on this.PLZ (Kishorebt11@gmail.com)

Comment: No Reputation !!! Sorry :(

Comment: Kishore B T my Skype ID

Comment: Thanks @Ratan, For your concerns on helping but im helpless on this.